# Comparing utf decoded value with a string value

Tags: python, string, pyserial, utf

I have been trying to compare the UTF-decoded data from `pyserial` with a value of a similar data type. However, it never returns true.

Please refer to the Python 3 code below:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports
import serial

serialInst = serial.Serial()

serialInst.bandrate = 9600
serialInst.port = portvar
serialInst.open()


while True:

    if serialInst.in_waiting:

        packet = serialInst.readline()
    
        num = packet.decode("utf")
    
        print("num is: ")
        print(num)       # prints 0
        print(type(num)) # returns <class 'str'>
        
        print(num == '0') # returns false
```

Comment: Can you share the value of `packet` (`print(repr(packet)))`?

Comment: print(repr(packet)) returns b'0\r\n'

Comment: There's your answer: `b'0\r\n'` is `0` followed by a carriage return and a newline - you should see an extra blank line when you print `num`.  Try `num = packet.decode('utf').strip()`

Comment: Thank you so much!!